# How to return the variable of a second largest value

Tags: javascript

I want to find the VARIABLE of my second largest value. I can find correctly about the second largest number, but I want to find the variable instead of value. For example, I got 4 column which is A, B, C and D.

A    B    C    D

1   4    2    3

I want the function return my second larger number is D instead of 3.
Below are my code.

```
var myArray = [totL,totO,totG,totB];
function findSecondLargeNumber(arr)
{
    var fLargeNum = 0;
    var sLargeNum = 0;
    var largename="";
    var key;
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(fLargeNum < arr[i])
        {
            sLargeNum = fLargeNum;
            fLargeNum = arr[i];
            key=i;
        }
        else if(sLargeNum < arr[i])
        {
            sLargeNum = arr[i];
            key=i;
        }
    }

    if(key==0 )
    {
        largename="A";

    }
    else if(key==1 )
    {
        largename="B";

    }

    else if(key==2 )
    {
        largename="C";

    }

    else if(key==3 )
    {
        largename="D";

    }

    return largename;

}
```

This is incorrect when I test it, can someone point me the error?

Comment: *"This is incorrect when I test it, can someone point me the error?"* You never set `key` anywhere.

Comment: I set it after fLargeNum = arr[i];   and  sLargeNum = arr[i];

Comment: even I set it already, but still can't get the correct answer.

Comment: *"I set it after fLargeNum = arr[i]; and sLargeNum = arr[i];"* That code wasn't there when I posted the comment.

Comment: yes, sorry about that, I edited already, but still not working for me. I don't know where's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a total different approach:

```js
    var columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
    var myArray = [1,3,4,2];
    function findSecondLargeNumber(arr){
        // Map column names to the input array values
        var map = arr.map(function(number, index){
            return {column: columns[index], value: number}
        });
        // sort the mapped array by the values
        map = map.sort(function(a,b){
            return a.value - b.value;
        });
        // return the column of the second last element in the sorted array
        return map[map.length-2].column;
    }
    console.log(findSecondLargeNumber(myArray));
```

Comment: Thanks! This work for me, even though is a different way :)

Comment: @Beginner: It's a more "functional programming" way. It's also dramatically slower and more complicated than your approach. :-) (The former isn't usually an issue. The latter, IMHO, is.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thank you, your code also fine, but I can't get the result and maybe is my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @Beginner: I don't understand what you mean by "I can't get the result" -- the snippet in my answer runs and produces the correct result. I'm not suggesting you change your accepted answer, I'm just confused about what it is you're not getting in regard to my minor modification of your code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess the sorting part is not necassary here, one could use the same for-loop to get the second-largest number as in his original code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My guess is he needs to map different column names than just A,B,C,D to the numbers, therfor he didn't know what to do with String.fromCharCode...

Comment: @Danmoreng: Perhaps, but I answered that question.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You're never setting `key` anywhere, so it won't equal any of those values.</s> As of your edit, you are, but to the wrong value. You need to remember where you found the largest value, and then set `key` to that when you shuffle that down to be the second-largest value.

But it can be a lot simpler than that, see comments (I've used `sKey` instead of `key`, because we need to track `fKey`):

```js
// NOTE ASSUMPTION: That the values are always >0 and not NaN
var myArray = [23, 42, 51, 12]; //[totL,totO,totG,totB];
var names = ["L", "O", "G", "B"];
function findSecondLargeNumber(arr)
{
    var fLargeNum = -Infinity;
    var sLargeNum = 0;
    var fKey = -1;
    var sKey = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (fLargeNum < arr[i])
        {
            // If we had a previous largest number, remember it and its index
            // as the second largest
            sLargeNum = fLargeNum;
            sKey = fKey;
            // Remember the largest number and its index
            fLargeNum = arr[i];         
            fKey = i;
        }
    }
    if (sKey === -1) {
        // Single-entry arrays have no second-largest
        return undefined;
        sKey = fKey;
    }
    // Return L, O, G, or B depending; note this assumes the array never has more than four entries
    return names[sKey];
}
console.log(findSecondLargeNumber(myArray));
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want LOGB instead of ABCD?

Comment: @Beginner: Well, that's not what your question asked. Assuming you know the array will never have more than four elements: `return "LOGB".charAt(sKey);` (or `return ["L", "O", "G", "B"][sKey];`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How do I get that stackoverflow Run code snipped?

Comment: @Danmoreng: It's the `[<>]` toolbar button.

Comment: @Beginner: I've updated the answer to fold in the LOGB thing. (Again, to be clear: I do not suggest changing your accepted answer.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, I was really appreciated for your help, I try already and it works for me too now your code. I think just now is my problem.Your code is fine.I'm sorry for my problem. :)

Comment: @Beginner: No worries! Happy coding!